# Is there any possibility to retrieve square size images from Wikipedia?

Tags: image, crop, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

Is there any possibility to retrieve square size images from Wikipedia instead of proportional ones, is there method out there to crop images on the fly?
for example

```
http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6a/Johann_Sebastian_Bach.jpg/81px-Johann_Sebastian_Bach.jpg
```

will retrieve the **81x100** size image, Is it possible to have the **100x100** pixel one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not. Thumbnails support only (down)scaling and conversion to PNG format, to generate fast and small previews. They are not supposed to do advanced and arbitrary image manipulation operations.

If you want square images, crop them on the fly after downloading.